# Spring MVC ModelAndView not working 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am getting 404 while trying to get URL"http://localhost/demo_spring/letsgo/find"
where it resolutes to search.jsp page (as in snippet below)

**Error Message:
*HTTP Status 404 - /demo_spring/letsgo/WEB-INF/views/search.jsp***

I have checked and its working for 
"http://localhost/demo_spring/letsgo/go" which produces JSON and also for

root url "http://localhost/demo_spring/letsgo" which returns index.jsp

Directory structure:

WEB-INF/VIEWS

-index.jsp

-search.jsp

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/letsgo")
public class IntroController
{   
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView v1 = new ModelAndView("index");
        v1.addObject("attributeName", "attributeValue");
        return v1;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="find",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView findloc() {
        ModelAndView op = new ModelAndView("search");
        op.addObject("attributeName", "attributeValue");
        return op;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="go",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public  String welcome3() {
        try
        {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString("Check for json");
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Dispatcher mapping**

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Sprin-mvc.xml configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

      <!-- View Handler -->
                 <bean id="multipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="text/xml"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                <entry key="less" value="text/html"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>


               <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Remove `@ResponseBody` for `findloc` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `InternalViewResolver` configuration, the prefix should be

```
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
```

not

```
  <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"/>
```

Notice the / before WEB-INF.

You should also remove `@ResponseBody` from the method `findLoc`as mentioned by [JavaGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3532826/javaghost). `@ResponseBody`  indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body

Comment: Got it that missing "/" was the problem. Also will check out the @ResponseBody annotation again.
Can't emphasize how much this has helped! Great answer! (Y)